# Creating a Similarity Matrix from Raw Card-Sort Data

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, similarity, tidyr

I have a data set from an online card sorting activity. Participants were presented with a random subset of Cards (from a larger set) and asked to create Groups of Cards they felt were similar to one another. Participants were able to create as many Groups as they liked and name the Groups whatever they wanted.

An example data set is something like this:

```
Data <- structure(list(Subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Card = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 12L, 13L, 14L), .Label = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N"), class = "factor"), 
    Group = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3", "Cat4", 
    "Cat5"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Subject", "Card", 
"Group"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

From these data I'd like to create a similarity matrix, ideally of proportion or percentage of total counts where items were grouped together.

Something like these:

Count:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N
A       0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
B   0       0   0   1   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   1
C   0   0       0   0   1   2   0   0   0   0   2   1   0
D   1   0   0       0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
E   1   1   0   0       0   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   1
F   0   0   1   0   0       1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
G   0   0   2   0   1   1       0   0   0   0   1   2   0
H   1   0   0   1   0   0   0       0   1   0   0   0   0
I   0   2   0   0   1   0   0   0       0   0   0   0   1
J   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0       1   0   0   0
K   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1       0   0   0
L   0   0   2   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0       1   0
M   0   0   1   0   1   0   2   0   0   0   0   1       0
N   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
```

Every subject named their Groups differently, so it's not possible to index by Group.

In addition to counts, I'd also like to generate a similarity matrix that reports the percentage of participants, who were presented with a particular pair of `Cards`, that grouped those two `Cards` together.

From the example data set, this as a result:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N
A       0   0   50  50  0   0   50  0   0   0   0   0   0
B   0       0   0   50  0   0   0   100 0   0   0   0   100
C   0   0       0   0   50  67  0   0   0   0   100 50  0
D   50  0   0       0   0   0   50  0   0   0   0   0   0
E   50  50  33  0       0   33  0   50  0   0   33  50  50
F   0   0   50  0   0       50  0   0   0   0   0   0   100
G   0   0   67  0   33  50      0   0   0   0   50  100 0
H   50  0   0   50  0   0   0       0   100 0   0   0   0
I   0   100 0   0   50  0   0   0       0   0   0   0   100
J   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   100 0       100 0   0   0
K   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   100     0   0   0
L   0   0   100 0   33  0   50  0   0   0   0       50  0
M   0   0   50  0   50  0   100 0   0   0   0   50      0
N   0   100 0   0   50  100 0   0   100 0   0   0   0
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

***Edit:*** While the answer below works for the example data. It doesn't seem to work for my actual data posted here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mhqwyok0nmvt3g9/Sim_Example.csv?dl=0

For example, in those data I manually count 22 pairings of "Aircraft" and "Airport", which would be ~55%. But the answer below yields a count of 12 and 60%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited** solution based on OP's requirement clarification

Step 1. Process data to create card pairs & whether they've been grouped together by any user:

```
library(tidyverse); library(data.table)

Data.matrix <- Data %>% 

  # convert data into list of data frames by subject
  split(Data$Subject) %>%

  # for each subject, we create all pair combinations based on the subset cards he 
  # received, & note down whether he grouped the pair into the same group 
  # (assume INTERNAL group naming consistency. i.e. if subject 1 uses group names such 
  # as "cat", "dog", "rat", they are all named exactly so, & we don't worry about 
  # variations / typos such as "cat1.5", "dgo", etc.)
  lapply(function(x){
    data.frame(V1 = t(combn(x$Card, 2))[,1],
               V2 = t(combn(x$Card, 2))[,2],
               G1 = x$Group[match(t(combn(x$Card, 2))[,1], x$Card)],
               G2 = x$Group[match(t(combn(x$Card, 2))[,2], x$Card)],
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
      mutate(co.occurrence = 1,
             same.group = G1==G2) %>%
      select(-G1, -G2)}) %>%

  # combine the list of data frames back into one, now that we don't worry about group 
  # names, & calculate the proportion of times each pair is assigned the same group, 
  # based on the total number of times they occurred together in any subject's 
  # subset.
  rbindlist() %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(V1.sorted = min(V1, V2),
         V2.sorted = max(V1, V2)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(V1.sorted, V2.sorted) %>%
  summarise(co.occurrence = sum(co.occurrence),
            same.group = sum(same.group)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  rename(V1 = V1.sorted, V2 = V2.sorted) %>%
  mutate(same.group.perc = same.group/co.occurrence * 100) %>%

  # now V1 ranges from A:M, where V2 ranges from B:N. let's complete all combinations
  mutate(V1 = factor(V1, levels = sort(unique(Data$Card))),
         V2 = factor(V2, levels = sort(unique(Data$Card)))) %>%
  complete(V1, V2, fill = list(NA))

> Data.matrix
# A tibble: 196 x 5
       V1     V2 co.occurrence same.group same.group.perc
   <fctr> <fctr>         <dbl>      <int>           <dbl>
 1      A      A            NA         NA              NA
 2      A      B             1          0               0
 3      A      C             2          0               0
 4      A      D             2          1              50
 5      A      E             2          1              50
 6      A      F             2          0               0
 7      A      G             2          0               0
 8      A      H             2          1              50
 9      A      I             1          0               0
10      A      J             1          0               0
# ... with 186 more rows

# same.group is the number of times a card pair has been grouped together.
# same.group.perc is the percentage of users who grouped the card pair together.
```

Step 2. Create separate matrices for count & percentage:

```
# spread count / percentage respectively into wide form

Data.count <- Data.matrix %>%
  select(V1, V2, same.group) %>%
  spread(V2, same.group, fill = 0) %>%
  remove_rownames() %>%
  column_to_rownames("V1") %>%
  as.matrix()

Data.perc <- Data.matrix %>%
  select(V1, V2, same.group.perc) %>%
  spread(V2, same.group.perc, fill = 0) %>%
  remove_rownames() %>%
  column_to_rownames("V1") %>%
  as.matrix()
```

Step 3. Convert the upper triangular matrices into symmetric matrices (note: I've just found a shorter & neater solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29857455/8449629)):

```
# fill up lower triangle to create symmetric matrices
Data.count[lower.tri(Data.count)] <- t(Data.count)[lower.tri(t(Data.count))]
Data.perc[lower.tri(Data.perc)] <- t(Data.perc)[lower.tri(t(Data.perc))]

# ALTERNATE to previous step
Data.count <- pmax(Data.count, t(Data.count))
Data.perc <- pmax(Data.perc, t(Data.perc))
```

Step 4. Get rid of the diagonals since there's no point pairing a card with itself:

```
# convert diagonals to NA since you don't really need them
diag(Data.count) <- NA
diag(Data.perc) <- NA
```

Step 5. Verify the results:

```
> Data.count
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N
A NA  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
B  0 NA  0  0  1  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  1
C  0  0 NA  0  1  1  2  0  0  0  0  2  1  0
D  1  0  0 NA  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
E  1  1  1  0 NA  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  1
F  0  0  1  0  0 NA  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
G  0  0  2  0  1  1 NA  0  0  0  0  1  2  0
H  1  0  0  1  0  0  0 NA  0  1  0  0  0  0
I  0  2  0  0  1  0  0  0 NA  0  0  0  0  1
J  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0 NA  1  0  0  0
K  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1 NA  0  0  0
L  0  0  2  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0 NA  1  0
M  0  0  1  0  1  0  2  0  0  0  0  1 NA  0
N  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0 NA

> Data.perc
   A   B   C  D  E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N
A NA   0   0 50 50   0   0  50   0   0   0   0   0   0
B  0  NA   0  0 50   0   0   0 100   0   0   0   0 100
C  0   0  NA  0 33  50  67   0   0   0   0 100  50   0
D 50   0   0 NA  0   0   0  50   0   0   0   0   0   0
E 50  50  33  0 NA   0  33   0  50   0   0  50  50  50
F  0   0  50  0  0  NA  50   0   0   0   0   0   0 100
G  0   0  67  0 33  50  NA   0   0   0   0  50 100   0
H 50   0   0 50  0   0   0  NA   0 100   0   0   0   0
I  0 100   0  0 50   0   0   0  NA   0   0   0   0 100
J  0   0   0  0  0   0   0 100   0  NA 100   0   0   0
K  0   0   0  0  0   0   0   0   0 100  NA   0   0   0
L  0   0 100  0 50   0  50   0   0   0   0  NA  50   0
M  0   0  50  0 50   0 100   0   0   0   0  50  NA   0
N  0 100   0  0 50 100   0   0 100   0   0   0   0  NA
```

Comment: I get an error with the above `Error in select(., -G1, -G2) : unused arguments (-G1, -G2)`
Also the percentages seem off. I think the percentages should be the percentage relative to the total count

Comment: @JLC: change that to `dplyr::select(., -G1, -G2)`. I suspect you have the another package with a similarly named function loaded somewhere? I used to get this error myself when `MASS::select` masked `dplyr::select`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked, but the percentages are off by a bit

Comment: `rbindlist` is from the `data.table` package. Please see first line in code where I indicated the packages to be loaded.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still checking percentages with the real data and they aren't quite matching

Comment: With regards to the percentages, I think that depends on what you mean by total count. My interpretation was that of number of times users grouped each pair together, divided by the total number of times users were given the opportunity to group them together. E.g take the pair A-E. Both cards appeared to Users 1 & 3, and only User 1 assigned them into the same category. So I calculated that as 50% of users assessing A-E t be similar. User 2 received card E but not card A, so he did not assess A-E at all. If that doesn't fit your use case, you can tweak calculations in the relevant steps.

Comment: I've updated the original question. To align with the online data, I need to calculate the percentage of participants that group any two `Cards` together

Comment: I'll take a look later.

Comment: Thank you for your help! While your elegant solution works well for the sample data, I can't get it to work accurately with my actual data. I've now uploaded some real data and an explanation of where the inaccuracies are.

Comment: @JLC: Have modified step 1 of my solution. Reason for the issue was that pairing B-A was counted separately from pairing A-B.

Comment: I get an error at `dplyr::mutate(V1.sorted = min(V1, V2),
         V2.sorted = max(V1, V2))` :
`Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: <U+0091>min<U+0092> not meaningful for factors.`

Comment: They shouldn be character strings rather than factors. See `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` argument in the `lapply()` step.

Comment: V1 and V2 are listed as factors for each subject in Data.matrix

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153541/discussion-between-z-lin-and-jlc).